# retrieve data from localstorage to be able to publish a post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

[image]Hello I would like to retrieve the user in my users table (id) so that the user can publish a post because it retrieves the userid and the token for me while I would like the userid

```
export default function Share() {
    const [publier, setPublier] = useState('')

    const handlePublier = (e) => {
        setPublier(e.target.value)
      }
    const register = () => {
        const posterId = localStorage.getItem('users')
        let objSo = JSON.parse(posterId)
        const poster = objSo.user
        axios.post('http://localhost:4200/api/post/',
         { posterId: posterId, message: publier }).then((response) =>{ console.log(response) })

    }


  return (
    <div className='share'>
        <div className="shareTop">
            <img className='shareProfilImg' src="/assets/person/1.jpeg" alt="" />
            <input placeholder='Que veux-tu publier ?' className='shareInput' onChange={handlePublier} />
        </div>
        <hr className='shareHr'/>
        <div className="shareBottom">
            <div className="shareOptions">
                <div className="shareOption">
                    <PermMedia htmlColor='tomato' className='shareIcon' />
                    <span className='shareOptionText'>Photo ou Vidèo</span>
                </div>
                <button className='shareButton' onClick={register}>Publier</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you be more clear what's the issue is ?

Comment: @AmanSadhwani sorry is it better this way? I would like to retrieve the user in the users table and only the user, not the token

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you aren't passing the `const poster = objSo.user` to axios at all.

See if this works:

```
const register = () => {
    const posterId = localStorage.getItem('users')
    let objSo = JSON.parse(posterId)
    const poster = objSo.user

    axios.post('http://localhost:4200/api/post/',
     // Passing `poster` which I assume is the `user` id that you want
     { posterId: poster, message: publier }).then((response) =>{ console.log(response) })

}
```